# Characters do not show in right way after changing hosting company?

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I had many websites with turkish letters and characters on some hosting company and it works fine.
After changing the hosting company and moving the websites there the characters were shown as (? or unknown symbols).

I did not change any thing in the code.

```
The previous hosting PHP version :5.3.25
The current hosting PHP version :5.3.28
```

Note: I write variables in the code and their turkish values are stored in separate file tr.lng.

tr.lng:

```
﻿<?php
define("RANK","Sıra");
define("NAME","İsim");
define("TRAFFIC","Hit");
define("POINTS","Puan");
define("COMMENTS","Mesajlar");
define("COMMENT","Mesaj");
define("BONUS","Üye Bonusu");
define("ANALYSIS","İncele");
define("PERMISSION","Üye Kabul");
define("COMPANY","Site");
define("INFORMATION","Bilgi");
define("USERNAME","Kullanıcı");
define("REPLY","Cevap Yaz");
define("CAPTCHA","Doğrulama");
define("LINK","Giriş Linki");
define("NEWS","Haber");
define("DATE","Tarih");
define("ADD_REPLY","Cevap yaz");
define("ADD_COMMENT","Mesaj yaz");
?>
```

I call the file in the first line of my code index.php
And I use in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=latin-1" />
```

Note: If i did not use the lang file and i just write the words in turkish in the code they work fine but i need to write them in file to change the language easily.

Am I doing something wrong?? why are they shown like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your default character set in PHP.

Set the required character set in your `php.ini` file as such:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"; /*Replace utf-8 with required characters set*/
```

This line may already exist in your `php.ini`, however it may have the wrong character set specified or be commented out *(line will prefixed with **;**)*

Comment: I tried it but not working : all of the following are not working(utf-8, ISO-8859-9, latin-1). Affect the page but not solve the problem only make it worse

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9" />`